# Ascii character Issue in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem about running sql script in Oracle Sql Developer.

There is an issue regarding invalid character.

How can I fix it?

```
CREATE TABLE `users_roles` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`role_id`),

  KEY `FK_ROLE_idx` (`role_id`),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_USER_05` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
  REFERENCES `user` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

  CONSTRAINT `FK_ROLE` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) 
  REFERENCES `role` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
Error report -
ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
```

Comment: Remove bacticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used MySQL syntax for your statement.  In Oracle, this would look more like:

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles (
  user_id int not null,
  role_id int not null,

  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id),

  CONSTRAINT FK_USER_05 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),

  CONSTRAINT FK_ROLE FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_users_roles_role_id ON users_roles(role_id) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5a9b513c59fa099bfcd222fb069bdd91) is a db<>fiddle.